# Split Up Text In A Column

Tags: sql

I have this piece of text that is stored in our MS-SQL database (ignore the quotes and no, I can't redesign how this work specifically):

> "TEST|00000298398293|EQ5|Patient"

Now, when I do a simple select, I get that result being returned. What I'd like to do is split that string based on the "|" character and return the individual strings associated with this string, so that I could have "TEST", "0000298398293", "EQ5" and "Patient" in different fields. How can I do this? In PHP, you can use the explode method, is there something like that in MS-SQL?

Comment: @bluefeet i don't think so, bardoo is asking to split text of a column... but not into different rows!

Comment: This is pretty ugly; databases were designed for structured data and you're losing a lot of their advantages by storing data in this format. I agree with Ivo, you might want to consider a redesign if you have that luxury.

Comment: @bluefeet whatever... its not my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's surely not the most elegant solution but i've used in in the past:

```
DECLARE @Sql varchar(50) = 'TEST|00000298398293|EQ5|Patient'


SELECT
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@sql,'|','.'),4),
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@sql,'|','.'),3),
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@sql,'|','.'),2),
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@sql,'|','.'),1)
```

**Notice : This only works if you have 3 pipes, eventually consider to redesign your database in the future!**